# Split array into new array based on property occurences

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have an array of objects that I would like to turn into an array (or array-like) object where the keys are the unique values for that given property (something like SQL group by).

[fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/wuQ3K/2/)

```
var obj = [
   {
      "ClaimId":"111",
      "DrugName":"AMBIEN CR",
      "PatientId":1571457415
   },
   {
      "ClaimId":"222",
      "DrugName":"AMBIEN CR",
      "PatientId":1571457415
   },
   {
      "ClaimId":"333",
      "DrugName":"LOTREL",
      "PatientId":1571457415
   },
   {
      "ClaimId":"444",
      "DrugName":"METHYLPREDNISOLONE",
      "PatientId":1571457415
   },
   {
      "ClaimId":"555",
      "DrugName":"CYMBALTA",
      "PatientId":1513895252
   },
   {
      "ClaimId":"666",
      "DrugName":"CYMBALTA",
      "PatientId":1513895252
   },
   {
      "ClaimId":"777",
      "DrugName":"CYMBALTA",
      "PatientId":1513895252
   },
   {
      "ClaimId":"888",
      "DrugName":"CYMBALTA",
      "PatientId":1513895252
   },
   {
      "ClaimId":"147503879TMQ",
      "DrugName":"CYMBALTA",
      "PatientId":1513895252
   },
   {
      "ClaimId":"999",
      "DrugName":"CYMBALTA",
      "PatientId":1513895252
   }
]
function splitBy(data, prop) {
        var returnObj = {};
        var returnArray = [];
        $.each(data, function (ix, val) {
            if (returnObj[val[prop]] === undefined) {
                returnObj[val[prop]] = [];
                returnObj[val[prop]].push(val);
            }


        });
        console.log(returnObj);
    }
splitBy(obj,'PatientId');
```

In the fiddle you can see that I get the keys of the array like I want (the two unique values in the PatientId property) but I only get the first value.  I understand that's because once the key is no longer undefined, then this check isn't ran, but I couldn't figure out quite how to do it and this is as close as I got.  How can I do this with one iteration over this collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I only get the first value.

That's because you only push the first value - when there had been no key. Change the

```
        if (returnObj[val[prop]] === undefined) {
            returnObj[val[prop]] = [];
            returnObj[val[prop]].push(val);
        }
```

to

```
        if (returnObj[val[prop]] === undefined) {
            returnObj[val[prop]] = [];
        }
        returnObj[val[prop]].push(val);
```

Comment: After a few minutes of looking, this is exactly that I was trying to do with ternary logic if the val[prop] === something something..here, you simply push it onto the correct key because the correct key is what's being iterated over. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/wuQ3K/4/)***

You almost had it, but you forgot the else clause for once the key existed

```
if (returnObj[val[prop]] === undefined) {
    returnObj[val[prop]] = [];
    returnObj[val[prop]].push(val);
}else{
    returnObj[val[prop]].push(val);
}
```

Comment: No, using `else` and an empty array literal would ignore the first occurence.

Comment: With the `else` you have the same line twice; it shouldn't be in the `if` at all, because you want it to run every time.

Comment: @Bergi I thought you were wrong at first, but...I was wrong when I realized that my new array was only 8 elements :(

Comment: @Bergi - In your version it would. But not in the OP's code. Your comment is not relevant.

Comment: @Mathletics - That is true, the else is not essentially required as much as the inclusion of the `push`, it is more of a readability issue. However, without refactoring the op's code, it is required.

Comment: @TravisJ: Without the whole code (and without looking at your fiddle), I first thought you would suggest to insert an `else` before the existing `push` statement. It didn't come to my mind that you would duplicate the line :-)

Comment: @Bergi - I prefer to offer as easy to read of an example as possible without refactoring the OP's code. I think it allows them to make their own decisions on which direction their code should go. I understand the assumption though.